# Couldn't add dependency to pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I coudn't add new dependency to pom.xml.

My steps :

1. I use Spring Template Project MVC.
2. Open in Eclise pom.xml.
3. Open "Dependency" tab.
4. Add my required dependency: spring-tx.
5. Save my changes. But my changes didn't affect Dependency "Hierarchy" and "Effective POM" tabs.
6. Clean and Build Project.
   In my pom.xml dependency spring-tx disappeared. So my problem still here.

How can I add dependency to pom.xml and save it into when project Build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pom "editor" tab instead.

Comment: I couldn't find it. Should I install maven plugin for this? Already it isn't installed.

Comment: If you have the "Dependency" Tab, then you have the Maven Plugin (M2e) allready installed.

Answer (score 0):

Or next time, you can use any file editor to add the dependencies. Highly recommend Notepad++.